# Is calling a void method like copying the code?

Tags: java

I have a problem with a program I am writing and I am trying to optimize it best as possible because a lot of lag is being generated as a result. I need to know if calling a void method from another method is just like copying the code.
As an example, say i have method "a", i call the void method "b" from "a". Does "a" wait for all the code in "b" to finish before proceeding?

Comment: If you're trying to improve lag, you're barking up the wrong tree with this question since the amount of code text is not directly associated with program responsiveness. Get a profiler, and use the profiler. Then fix the bottlenecks that it finds for you.

Comment: Yes. Just calling a method does not magically introduce asynchronicity. I can guarantee you right now that the reason for your lag is because of exponential algorithms or inefficient resource handling. It's not because you need to do micro optimizations such as inlining or whatever you're thinking.

Comment: thank you for your responses, I'll try to do that instead.

Comment: Waiting for a called method to finish, which is what does happen, is nothing whatsoever like copying the code.

Comment: @EJP whats the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially yes. Calling a void method or copying the code inside the caller is almost the same in terms of performance (if you call b only once per method a execution).
And the code will be executed sequentially.
If you want code inside method b to be executed in parallel you will need to create a thread. But doing this may raise other issues like concurrency.
Your problem seems to be related with the number of times you call method a or what you're doing inside a and b.
You can show us what your program does, your algorithm, and maybe you will have better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yeah, calling a void method is just like copying the code to where ever you called it. But when you end up using multiple times, it's quicker to define it in a separate method as opposed to writing it over and over and over.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. In basic you are making pointer to a code. But as long as you do not make it in really high numbers, it does not have real impact on performance.

Comment: 'Making pointer to a code' is meaningless, as is the question.

Comment: @EJP No, it's not. This way you can give the code a 'label' so it's easier to understand what caller do. You are poiting to a part of source code that has to be executed.